# Unexpected error while creating a record in a Client Script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Im doing a script that loop through a CSV import and create some records, but im getting an error trying to create a Cash Sale. I puted data indo all mandatory fields.

```
var venda = record.create({
    type: record.Type.CASH_SALE,
    isDynamic: true,
    defaultValues: {
    entity: nomeOcupante1
    }
});

venda.setValue({
fieldId: 'custbody_cpb_id_locacao',
value: idLocacao
}),

venda.selectNewLine({ 
sublistId: 'item' 
});

venda.setCurrentSublistValue({   
sublistId: 'item',
fieldId: 'item',
value: 1587 
});
venda.setCurrentSublistValue({
sublistId: 'item',
fieldId: 'quantity',
value: 1 
});

venda.setCurrentSublistValue({
sublistId: 'item',
fieldId: 'amount',
value: 10
});

venda.commitLine({ 
sublistId: 'item'
});



venda.save({
enableSourcing: true,
ignoreMandatoryFields: true
});
```

I expect to create some records and can update then through script.

Comment: You haven't shared the error you're getting, but you end your twelfth line with a comma (,) rather than a semi-colon (;) which I would expect would give you an error.

Comment: @Krypton Im getting an enexpected error, i fixed the ',' and i still getting the error...

Comment: You did not include the entire script, so there may be issues outside of the code snippet that you included.  I would suggest adding simple logging through this snippet and see where they stop logging.  That will easily tell you which piece is bad.  You could also try putting it in a try/catch block...  Though, most likely the exception that NetSuite returns will just be an unexpected error, there, as well.